# Capture User Feedback in TokBox WebRTC session

Tags: opentok, tokbox

I am able to have two users connect to a TokBox Session by providing a customised URL to a session.This URL actually ,internally, checks some params in our own server, and then renders control to JSP, which simply initiates a TOKBOX session.
However, i have a requirement of capturing the Userfeedback of the session, once the users terminate the session.The Feedback needs to be passed back to my own server,maybe by way of Return URL.
Is there a way to customise TOKBOX webRTC Session window, with Video/Audio component ,sort of opening inline in my own page instead of TOKBOX specific page.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically, you should use an OpenTok Server SDK in the language of your choice (sounds like Java) in order to create sessions and tokens. The rest of the logic to render your page is completely up to your application. There is no such thing as a TokBox specific page.

You should use the JavaScript client SDK (opentok.js) to listen for the `'sessionDisconnected'` event from the Session object. As long as your user's have a way to terminate their participation in the session which actually calls `session.disconnect()`, this event will be fired. At that point you can do whatever you like to collect feedback, such as redirect to a return URL.

Comment: I would have used SDK,but its not compatible with GoogleAppEngine/Java.Do you have a way to get this SDK working with appengine?
Yes probably i  can provide a button to terminate the session,and capture the feedback .Thanks.